# VSAM to PDS member

Tags: mainframe

Can we copy VSAM file to a PDS member?
eg. I have a VSAM file A.VSAM
I have a PDS. B.PDS which has members A,B
I want to copy my A.VSAM file to B.PDS(C) ... C is the new member in PDS.
Can I do this?

Thanks and Regards,
Manasi :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IDCAMS REPRO](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.zos.r10.idad400/reprol.htm) can do the job.

In your JCL:

- set **INFILE** DD to point to the VSAM input file
- set **OUTFILE** DD to point to the PDS member

Complete documentation for IDCAMS can be found in: [DFSMS Access Method Services for Catalogs](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/DGT2I210/CCONTENTS?DT=20020122184748)
. Look under REPRO (chapter 29)